скрипт для включения прокси на win 10
как сделать скрипт или бат файл, включающий/отключающий прокси на вин 10? находил батники в интернете, но там не был учтен нюанс - прокси приватный, имеет логин и пароль помимо адреса и порта. как реализовать включение прокси в один клик? (вариант включать через настройки винды не подходит). буду благодарен за помощь

Рекомендую статью о решении задачи прокси на Powershell, реализация которая может хотя бы частично помочь.
